# Let $u=u(x,y)$ be a differentiable function such that $u(x,x^{2}) = 1$ and $u_{x} (x,x^{2}) = x$. Find $u_{y} (x,x^{2})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

First of all I apologize for my English, it's not my first language and I'm not 100% sure of some of the English terminology. Sorry if I'm not super clear, I hope you can still understand my question!

I have a multi-variable calculus exercice I'm not sure how I'm supposed to solve:

Let $u=u(x,y)$ be a  differentiable function such that $u(x,x^{2}) = 1$ and $u_{x} (x,x^{2}) = x$. Find $u_{y} (x,x^{2})$.

The only thing I've come up with to try and solve is this:

Since $y$ is a funtion of $x$ here, is it true that $u_{x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+2x\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=x$?
It somehow doesn't seem to be right, and even if it is, I can't see how it helps me get then answer.

The solution is supposed to be $u_{y} (x,x^{2})=-\frac{1}{2}$, but I have no idea how to get that answer.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Fix some $x\ne0$, the goal is to find some $v$ such that $u(x,x^2+h)=u(x,x^2)+hv+o(h)$ when $h\to0$, then $v=u_y(x,x^2)$. For $|h|$ small enough, $x^2+h>0$ hence $x^2+h=z^2$ with $z=x+\frac{h}{2x}+o(h)$ hence $x=z-\frac{h}{2z}+o(h)$ and $$u(x,x^2+h)=u\left(z-\frac{h}{2z}+o(h),z^2\right)=u(z,z^2)-\frac{h}{2z}u_x(z,{}{}{}{}z^2)+o(h)=1-\frac{h}{2z}z+o(h),$$ that is, $u(x,x^2+h)=u(x,x^2)-\frac{h}2+o(h)$, qed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We compute using Leibniz rule

$$ 0 = \frac{d}{dx} u(x,x^2) = u_x(x,x^2) +  u_y(x,x^2) \cdot 2x
= x + 2x \cdot u_y(x,x^2) = x (1+ 2u_y(x,x^2)).$$

Hence

$$ u_y(x,x^2)=-\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: thanks, but I'm not entirely clear on why $\frac{\partial u(x,x^{2})}{\partial x}=0$?

Comment: It's not the partial derivative $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,x^2)$, it is the total derivative, i.e. $\frac{d}{dx} u(x,x^2) = \frac{d}{dx} f(x)$, where $f(x)=u(x,x^2)$. But we know $f(x)=1$, hence its derivative vanishs.